# Get group of logged in user in azure

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an application where there are two categories of document. For example suppose it as **ABC** and **DEF** .

Now there is Microsoft authentication is enabled for user to use my app.

Since there are two types of document, I have created two groups in azure where member of one group will only able to see document of category **ABC** while member of other group will be able to see document of category **DEF**.

I have fetched access token and tried to call following API

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf

But I got error message stating **Not Authorized**.

How can I able to retrieve group to which logged in user belongs so that I can use that data to show them required documents.

Thanks

**subham**

Comment: If you're looking for the (AAD) SecurityGroups for a user, go to the app registration in the Azure Active Directory, open its manifest and set `groupMembershipClaims` to be `SecurityGroup`. This will add all the SecurityGroups a user is a member of as claims in your token.

Comment: To be able to communicate with Graph, be sure to enable the right permission to read `memberOf`. Check the **Permissions** chapter of this article: [List memberOf](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof)

Comment: Ok thanks Rick. I'll let you know I got stucked.